# Unable To Run Test Cases in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When I run "pybot" command in command prompt, test cases are passed but when I run the same command in Jenkins it is showing error: **'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command**.

Error Image 
[image]

Comment: Can you give more information? What does your jenkins file look like for example?

Comment: I added jenkins error image plz see this

Comment: Hi, please paste the error as text into 'code' format. But, as you can see from the log, "pybot" is not recognized as internal or external command, so it means "pybot" command is not existing on the machine, where the code is being executed.. (missing in path, eg.)

Comment: If machine wont have Pybot command then how it can be possible to run test cases from cmd Promt using same command.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the screenshot which you provided- error is saying `command was not recognized as external or internal command`.

So, it means in your case 'pybot' command is not existing on the machine, where the code is being executed.

That can- if the program exists/ is installed- command is missing in the `PATH` variable.
refer to eg. to 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46200320/4892907 
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251740/4892907