# Jenkins - Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Tags: jenkins

When I run from the Command prompt on the window then it's working fine

cd C:\Users\user12\Desktop\Postman
Postman>newman run collection3.json

Both commands are working fine

Now when I setup in the jenkin and add the same above command and build it then getting -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['node' is not recognized as an internal or external command error with jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247396/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-error-with-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands

```
C: && cd Users\user12\Desktop\Postman

newman run collection3.json
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not Working-console Output

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Postman3>C:   && cd Users\user12\Desktop\Postman 
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Postman3>newman run collection3.json 
'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Postman3>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE